# UITableView scrolling although numberOfRows is 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am having a very difficult time understanding this. I have a UITableView which frameHeight is set at 200. Although I've set numberOfRows to 0, this UITableView still scrolls, any idea why? My understanding is that it will only scroll if the contentView height is bigger than the frameHeight right? But in the case of the numberOfRows of 0, the contentView should be 0?

Comment: Show us some code. Where are you getting a 0 for your numberOfRows? Maybe your code is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: I was just testing with a numberOfRows 0, hard coding it just to make sure why it's still scrolling

Comment: It turns out the scrolling was a bounce effect. So after I turn it off it didn't scroll anymore if the content size height is less than the frame. So how do I make such that the bounds is set only when the contentSize height is greater than the frame? Where should I have this settings at?

Comment: then you need to set that setting before return nuberofrow method, just add if condition that row value is greater then zero or what ever value you want to set, then bounce enable else bounce enable false that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Solution** use UITableViewStyleGrouped style

Because by default it is set to UITableViewStylePlain which shows empty cells too after displaying filled cells.

**Second Indirect Way**

```
if (table.contentSize.height < table.frame.size.height) {
   table.scrollEnabled = NO;
 }
else {
   table.scrollEnabled = YES;
 }
```

You can run this code after calling reloadData on the table, and it calculates the right sizes and appears to work.

**Edit 1**

Another way is to disable Bounce -> Bounces/ Bounce Vertically

Hope this will solve your problem